# Redis Pod to Python Pod readonly Issue

Tags: python, kubernetes, redis, azure-aks

I have multiple pods in my kubernetes environment, where two of them are Redis and Python, I am pushing some commands in Redis Pod and every few minutes a cron job is running which creates a python pod and reads if something is inserted in Redis, Python reads and execute that command.

Problem is: I am able to write from other pods to Redis and Python pod only reads that command, but it gives me readonly slave error.

I have tried changing my redis configuration like passing 'slaveof no one' parameter, replica-readonly is already set to 'no'. Tried installing Redis using configMaps and StatefulSets, but nothing seems to be working, stucked here from a month

Comment: Mayby you have set maxmemory?

Comment: maxmemory is default 0